# SharePoint 2010 Workflow Issue

Tags: designer-workflow

Although I am working in SP2013 the group that set up our farm disabled 2013 workflows.  OK so my issue is this: I have List "A" that has a number of Multi-line fields and I have List "B" with the same number of multi-line fields.  After List "A" line item is approved I want to Update List "B" with the same information.  The issue I am running into is that it won't update the line item.  I can copy all day but it won't update the line entry.  I tried one column at a time, adding signal flags, equated Title to Title from one list to the other and still it will not allow the overwrite of the data there.  How do I do this? Here is the simplest ite[image]m I have tried that will not work:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharePoint 2010 Workflow "**Copy list item**" action. Check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnwpowell/2009/01/02/sharepoint-designer-copy-list-item-workflow-activity-does-not-copy-all-fields/) post for detail.

**How the Copy List Item Activity Works**

The copy list item activity iterates through all the fields in the source list and tries to find a match in the target list.  The fields are considered compatible for copying when the following is true:

- The source and target field names are the same.  It compares the field name you see in the browser (SPField.Title), not the internal/static name (SPField.InternalName)
- The source and target field are the same type
- The source and target fields are compatible.  For example, if the source field allows multiple selections, but the target does not, or the source allows selecting people and groups, but the target only allows selecting people
- When the source field is a lookup to another list, the target field must use the same list
- The source field is not read only
- The source field is not a special field, such as ContentTypeId

After the field matches have been determined, a list item is created in the target list using a system update (does not trigger event receivers / workflows and the created by user is system).  In addition, when the field type is User, the user(s) are created in the target web if they don’t already exist.

**What Can Go Wrong**

There are two common symptoms and the underlying causes of each is human error.  But don’t beat yourself up; they are easy mistakes to make and correct.  Use the following to troubleshoot the issue:

- When a SPD workflow doesn’t copy one field to the target list:

  - The field names don’t match
  - The field names match, but the field type and the settings do not
- In a document library, when none of the fields are copied (except the file name), or when all the fields are copied but intermittently:

  - The issue is that everything is working as designed and the workflow hasn’t accounted for it!  There is a difference between New and Upload